# How to use Gmail app without any browsers installed?

Tags: gmail, browser

I had rooted my Android phone, and after uninstalling all browsers, I am unable to use the Gmail app on my phone. While I still get notification of Gmail in the notification bar, it closes as soon as I open the app.

I had tried some other apps (other than Android built-in apps for mail) like Microsoft Outlook, but the problem remains the same. On reinstalling the browser (like Chrome), my mail apps work properly.

Is it possible to use the Gmail app without browsers installed? Any solution including any third-party app is okay.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Android apps can make use of a WebView (web browser that runs inside the app).

Depending on the Android version Google preferred used [Chrome webbrowser app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.chrome) to provide this WebView or the [Chrome based WebView app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.webview).

Any other WebView capable web browser can also be used.

Go to **Settings -> System -> Developer options -> WebView implementation** to see and select the app that provide the WebView to all apps.

[image]

In your case the WebView app may be the best to install because it can't be used as stand-alone web browser but once installed GMail app should work again as it provides the necessary WebView component.