# Stop 'in app' ads from loading?

Tags: adb, google-play-services, android-10, ads

I noticed that ads inside apps are not loaded when Google Play Services' data connection is disabled and kind of formed the idea that it is responsible for loading these ads within the apps.

Is there any particular package (com.google.*) that I can disable to prevent ads from loading, that is, is any particular package solely responsible for this task (loading ads)?

Is there a way to stop these ads by disabling some such package or system app that would still let me use gmail, play store and other such services?

I am not looking for external ad blocking apps.

Answer (score 1):

Apps are self-contained. Even for ads delivered by Google AdMob, there is no ad-system component involved at all. Apps are loading ads and other data directly from the Internet.

Therefore, what you want is not possible. You can disable every app package by Google on your phone, but as long as the internet still works, the apps will show you ads.

The only system package that might be used is the WebView - a component that allows apps to display web pages - and ads are typically web content.

The problem is that many apps also use WebViews for displaying non-ad content, some apps even mainly consist of a WebView and the whole app consists of web pages.

The used WebView can be configured in Android developer options. On some devices, there is a separate WebView component installed, on others, the default web browser or an installed Chrome app is used as a WebView provider.

It is possible to develop an app that provides a WebView with an integrated ad-filter, but I have not heard of such an app.

## Ad-blocking WebView

It seems like there are already such apps available. Based on the information I found, [Adblock Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.adblockplus.browser) should provide a WebView implementation with integrated ad-blocking (not yet tested).
You have to install this app and make it the default WebView provider as shown in [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/228544/2241).

However, using that app has one major disadvantage: it is based on Chromium, the open-source part of Google Chrome. Therefore, all vulnerabilities found in Chrome also apply to this web browser. So if you want to stay secure, every time a security update for Chrome is published (which happens some times multiple times a week) the developers of Adblock Browser need to update their project, incorporate all necessary changes, and also publish an update. Otherwise, apps that use WebView for regular (non-ad related) purposes may otherwise be vulnerable to an attack.

In the end, this is an advantage of ad-filtering external apps like [Blokada](https://blokada.org/) or on the network level in your Wifi network, you can install a gateway like [Pi-hole](https://pi-hole.net/). Both filter apps and Pi-Hole work very similarly. You don't need to update them so often as security vulnerabilities are not so often found in such apps/systems.

Answer (score 0):

I use NetGuard to block Google Ads service requests and it works so well that I don't see a single ad in apps. But you need a NetGuard premium for blocking those domains.

I also restricted my Play Service from internet connections and permissions. This helps a lot in my device. And I don't think you can disable any system app. They still can do anything; at least Google apps can ignore these.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AdAway](https://adaway.org/), it works without root, the only ad it still works is from YouTube. Now I don't see any ads in apps, I see no apps in Chrome too.

Well, of course i still see the Ad Frame, but it get an error showing the ad, so technically you're not seeing an ad.